# How to block or remove bad sectors in my HDD

Tags: bad-sectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bad Sectors Relocation on Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/37189/bad-sectors-relocation-on-windows-xp)

I know that bada sectors are like virus and they spread and make my HDD die. But I want to know if there any way of blocking or removing them temporarily or permanently from an HDD, if there any software that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad sectors are automatically ignored by your computer. You do not need extra software for this. That said, if your harddrive has bad sectors, don't store anything important on it. You'll likely notice that the apparent size of your harddrive will decrease as bad sectors are ignored. Depending on your OS, they might be marked automatically or in the progress of being scanned by something like `chkdsk`.